# How to convert tuple into initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, stdtuple

I make large tuple with std::make_tuple function.

something like this

```cpp
template <class ...T>
QCborArray array(const T&... args) {
    return {args...};
}
```

but with tuple instead of parameter pack

Comment: An `std::initializer_list` has to be of a single type see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @RichardCritten C++ automatically calls QCborValue's constructor for all values making them of same type https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcborarray.html#QCborArray-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and a variadic lambda to do this.  That would look like

```
template <class Tuple>
QCborArray array(Tuple&& tuple) {
    return std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return QCborArray{args...}; },
                      std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Before, posting question, I tried std::apply with function but it did not worked https://hatebin.com/gygiwasazu. Also why you added std::forward. your previous code without it was working as expected

Comment: @尤金寶漢子 I added the `std::forward` to enable perfect forwarding.  Without it, moves turn into copies and that could hurt performance.

Comment: @尤金寶漢子 Also, I can't visit that link.  Could you share the code using this link?  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2856178439b99c0.

Comment: @尤金寶漢子 That doesn't work because `_from` is a function template, so the compiler doesn't know which instantiation of the template to use.  You would either have to cast it to the correct function pointer type, or wrap it in a lambda like `return std::apply([](auto&&... args){ return _from(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }, tuple);`